# How to identify observations with multiple matching patterns and create another variable in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a broad industry category from detailed categories in my data. I am wondering where am I going wrong in creating this with grepl in R?

My example data is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(county = c(01001, 01002, 02003, 04004, 08005, 01002, 02003, 04004),
                  ind = c("0700","0701","0780","0980","1000","1429","0840","1500"))
```

I am trying to create a variable called industry with 2 levels (e.g., agri, manufacturing) with the help of grepl or str_replace commands in R.

I have tried this:

```
newdf$industry <- ""
newdf[df$ind %>% grepl(c("^07|^08|^09", levels(df$ind), value = TRUE)), "industry"] <- "Agri"
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I want to get the following dataframe as my result:

```
newdf <- data.frame(county = c(01001, 01002, 02003, 04004, 08005, 01002, 02003, 04004),
                 ind = c("0700","0701","0780","0980","1000","1429","0840","1500"),
                 industry = c("Agri", "Agri", "Agri", "Agri", "Manufacturing", "Manufacturing", "Agri", "Manufacturing"))
```

So my question is this, how do I specify if variable 'ind' starts with 07,08 or 09, my industry variable will take the value 'agri', if 'ind' starts with 10, 14 or 15, industry will be 'manufacturing'? Needless to say, there is a huge list of industry codes that I am trying to crunch in 10 categories, so looking for a solution which will help me do it with pattern recognition.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @svenhalvorson Thanks.. I tried this: ```df[df$ind %>% grepl(paste(c("^07|^08|^09", levels(df$ind)), collapse = '|')), "industry"] <- "Agri"
``` But it gave me this error again: (Warning message:
In grepl(., paste(c("^07|^08|^09", levels(df$ind)), collapse = "|")) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used)

Comment: Using integer division: `df$industry <- factor(as.numeric(as.character(df$ind)) %/% 1000 == 0, labels = c("Manufacturing", "Agri"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
newdf = df %>% 
  mutate(industry = ifelse(str_detect(string = ind,
                                      pattern = '^07|^08|^09'),
                          'Agri',
                          'Manufacturing'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, using `ifelse()` to add desired column to `df` data.frame

```
df$industry <- ifelse(grepl(paste0("^", c('07','08','09'), collapse = "|"), df$ind), "Agri", "Manufacturing")

> df
  county  ind      industry
1   1001 0700          Agri
2   1002 0701          Agri
3   2003 0780          Agri
4   4004 0980          Agri
5   8005 1000 Manufacturing
6   1002 1429 Manufacturing
7   2003 0840          Agri
8   4004 1500 Manufacturing
```